# Where can I find good references regarding to noise filtering and prediction in time series?

Tags: time-series, references, filter, noise

I want to model the error structure of every certain time period obtained from the past errors produced by the predictions of nonlinear time series.

I would like to know if someone knows specialized bibliography regarding to this topic.